# Star doesn't show on production with letsrate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I use letsrate gem, on development all work fine, but on production stars doesn't show why?
letsrate.js.erb file

```
$.fn.raty.defaults.path = "/assets"; 
$.fn.raty.defaults.half_show = true;  

$(function(){ 
    $(".star").raty({                  
        score: function(){
            return $(this).attr('data-rating')              
        }, 
        number: function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-star-count')
        },
        click: function(score, evt) {
            $.post('<%= Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers.rate_path %>', 
                {
                    score: score, 
                    dimension: $(this).attr('data-dimension'),  
                    id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
                    klass: $(this).attr('data-classname')
                }, 
                function(data) {
                    if(data) {
                        // success code goes here ... 
                    }
            });
        }                        
    });           
});
```

`$.fn.raty.defaults.path = "/assets";`

It works on development but doesn't work on production, I think it doesn't work because in production after assets precompile all images move to the public/assets path 
What do I need to do to show images?
mysite.com/assets/star-on-287807403acda8ff0b61388109ea5b6e.png
my images "stars" on this url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 step: Please paste the following lines to application.js file:

```
//= require jquery.raty
//= require letsrate
```

2 step: Execute the following cmd line in your terminal:

```
 rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

3 step: Copy .png files from /images folder into /public/assets directory

```
star-half.png
star-off.png
start-on.png
```

4 step: execute the following cmd line in your terminal:

```
rails s -e production
```

I am using NetBeans IDE environment, Rails 4.2 and letsrate gem 1.0.9